# Oracle sqlplus export using spool vs sql developer export

Tags: excel, oracle, export, sqlplus, spool

I'm running a query which results 100 000 records/rows of data. Using Spool command in sqlplus I generate a csv which stores all the output of the query.

The csv file with 100 000 records gives me a size of 2.5 GB approximately.

The same export option I'm doing it in sql developer which produces a file with size of 50 MB approximately.

How to reduce filesize during export using spool command?

Comment: They produce the same number of rows in the spooled files? ('export' means something specific in Oracle... are you actually spooling from SQL Developer, or exporting from the right-clck menu in the data grid?). Is the output data format the same in both? Have you done `set trimspool on` in SQL\*Plus, and if not, does that make any difference?

Comment: In addition to what Alex has asked, how are you generating the csv in sqlplus? Are you doing `select col1||','||col2||','||.... `?

Comment: Thats what I meant by 'output data format', but yes, that's clearer. The export format from SQL Developer (if not using spool) is also relevant. The question might really be 'how do I spool as CSV from SQL`*Plus'. Wonder if `colsep` is being used instead of concatenation, which would waste a lot of space?

Comment: You have not specified the version of Oracle. But if you are using 12.2, then simply use the CSV Markuo.

Comment: show us HOW you're doing the csv in both tools, otherwise we have to guess

Answer (score 0):

Add the following at the starting of your script

```
set term off
set feed off
set sqlformat csv
set heading off
```